# Why can't I use this where clause in my mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Objective**
>
> Create a trigger that matches newly-inserted instructors to a student
> in the same department that currently has no advisor, and inserts a
> corresponding record in the advisor table.

**Tables:**

```
student(id,name,dept_name,tot_cred)
instructor(id,name,dept_name,salary
advisor(s_id,i_id)
```

*Note: `student.dept_name` refers to student's major, `s_id` is associated with `student.id`, and `i_id` is associated with `instructor.id`.*

```
DELIMITER $$
   CREATE TRIGGER advisor_match AFTER INSERT ON instructor
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      UPDATE advisor a SET a.i_id = new.instructor.id +
         (SELECT a.s_id,s.dept_name 
         FROM student s LEFT OUTER JOIN advisor a
         WHERE a.s_id IS NULL AND s.dept_name = new.instructor.dept_name;);
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

There could potentially be more issues with this code than I'm aware but right now MySQL keeps throwing me an error about using this WHERE clause and I can't understand why.

Edit: fixed the code to reflect my current predicament which is that I'm now getting an error at my `END IF; END$$` line.

Edit 2: Removed `END IF;` because I'm not using an IF statement. All problems resolved now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Well now that I've made a few simple changes thanks to the suggestions below I'm getting a mysql syntax error right here: `IF; END$$`

Comment: Do you need the word IF?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is the first time I've ever written a trigger and the two examples used end if before ending the trigger so I just assumed that was standard mysql trigger syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the ON part after your JOIN, most likely:
ON s.id=a.s_id

You also need to alias advisor as a.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for IS NULL

```
WHERE a.s_id IS NULL AND s.dept_name = new.i.dept_name;);
```